# Show/ Hide column in dojo grid based on condition

Tags: javascript, dojo

Guys i have a column which i want to hide and show based on condition in settings ... so how to do that in dojo ... here is my code

```
this._grid = new Grid({
    myColumn,
    {field: 'description' ,label:'description', dismissOnEnter: false,  editor: 'textBox', autoSave: true, renderCell: function(object, data, td, options){
        td.innerHTML = data;
    }}]
});

var myColumn = {
    field: 'myColumn', 
    label: 'myColumn', 
    editor: Select,
    hidden:false, /* hide or show based on condition*/
    autoSave: true,
};
```

any help will be greatly appreciated ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `grid.layout.setColumnVisibility(0,true);` to show or hide a column of your grid dynamically.

If you have more columns to hide or show then use

```
grid.beginUpdate()

grid.layout.setColumnVisibility(i, visible);

grid.endUpdate();
```

i is the column index which you want to hide/show and visible is true/false

Hope this helps.

**********************update**********

adding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2w49nd5/33/)

**************update 2*****************

take a look into this extension

https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.2.1/doc/components/extensions/ColumnHider.md

Comment: I added a jsfiddle link please see if that helps

Comment: i ma using dgrid not enchance grid

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use CSS

> grid.styleColumn("idOfColumn", "display: none;");